# How to display the JSON data in a tabular form in react js?

Tags: json, reactjs

The db calls in the back end return JSON data,and in this data the number of rows and columns vary depending on the table from which the results are fetched

JSON data looks like this:

`Scenario 1 [ { "Column1": ABC, "Column2": "ABC", "Column3": ABC, "Column4": "ABC" }, ]

Scenario 2[ { "Column1": ABC, "Column2": "ABC", "Column3": ABC, "Column4": "ABC", "Column5": "ABC", "Column6": "ABC", "Column7": "ABC" } `

The JSON varies as shown above.Is it possible to display the varying JSON results in tabular form?

Comment: Everything is possible AFAIK depending on what your need is. So please elaborate on your need like what table structure you want

Comment: You already asked this question and it seems holded. Why do you repeat the question?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58218777/how-to-display-the-json-data-in-a-tabular-form-using-react-js

Comment: Well,the table structure is like any other table which displays the query results.For scenario  4 columns and 4 rows